# How do I change or switch the structure for mobile version?

Tags: html, css

For right now, this is my desktop version. My desktop will looks like that. image first and then content(h1 , p, button) , content(h1 , p, button) first and then image, etc...But I want to switch the html structure a little bit for the mobile version. It looks confuse for mobile version. I want the image show first and then the content(h1 , p, button) for all row-wrap in mobile. How do I do that? Can I do that with media queries or jquery? I don't want to use duplicate code for desktop and mobile.

my code
http://jsfiddle.net/0ucLzbkq/2/

```
    <section class="row-wrap">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/370x370/000/fff"> 

            <div class="poster-content">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <p>this is a paragraph</p>
                <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
                    <div class="btn">button</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <section class="row-wrap">
        <div class="row-inner">
             <div class="poster-content">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <p>this is a paragraph</p>
                <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
                    <div class="btn">button</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/370x370/000/fff"> 


        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to achieve this would be to include some of the content more than once and just display: none; the content you don't want. It's not the cleanest solution, but it doesn't add to much overhead to the filesize and is controllable without javascript.

If you really, really do not want to use duplicate code, take a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/category/Manipulation/

But I'd prefer to just stick with the easy display: none; method. For example:

```
<div class="responsive-image"> (enter the image or whatever here) </div>
```

In the CSS:

```
.responsive-image{display:none;}
```

Then in responsive.css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 860px){
.responsive-image{display:block}
}
```

This would hide the div responsive-image. But it would show if the screen is smaller than 860px.

But as said, if you want to use jquery for it, take a look at the manipulation api or take a look here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-dom.htm

Edited example:

HTML (put the mobile image DIV wherever you want it to be displayed:

```
<div class="desktop-image"> Whatever goes here. </div>
<div class="mobile-image"> Whatever goes here. </div>
```

main.css:

```
.desktop-image {}
.mobile-image{display:none;}
```

responsive.css:

```
@media (max-width: 860px) {
    .desktop-image{display:none;}
    .mobile-image{display:block;}
}
```

Just use the same image for both div's

Comment: I'm going to use the same image for desktop and mobile. I just want the html to switch in mobile .

Comment: You can do that the simple way I explained with the display:none method. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a media query is the best way to go.
You will have to set properties of several elements in your structure, so that they arrange the way you want.

Media queries are great for this kind of thing.
Other than this, you could try playing around with Bootstrap, maybe with the `col--md-1 ... 12` classes. They auto-arrange based on device width and height.

Comment: How do I do that with css media queries? I don't want to use bootstrap or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with jquery :

```
if ($(window).width() <= 600) {
    var poster = $(".poster").detach();
    $(".row-inner").append(poster);
}
```

I chose 600px randomly, you can choose whatever value you want.

If you want to mimic the media query function, you can add a resize event to your jquery :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 600) {
        var poster = $(".poster").detach();
        $(".row-inner").append(poster);
    }
});
```

but if you want it only for mobiles, it might not be useful.